# google visualization API - Hide data column from graphic

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I would like to know if anyone was able or know's any way I can hide/show a line from a AreaChart from google visualization API after it was loaded.

In a little more detail, say we have 8 lines in a area chart, but because they are so many, that makes the graph almost unreadable and confuse. So I want a piece of JavaScript code that can turn on or off theses lines after the chart is already built and available to the user in the browser.

When I say on/off anything goes, changing the opacity, removing the line, or anything that just makes it disappear from the graph.

I am using CSS styling when building the charts (on the JavaScript that builds it, using options (series) on the `chart.draw(data, options)`.

I can't change the arrays of data I have. So I'm not looking for a dynamic data, CSS and JavaScript solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think we need to see a code example of how you are creating the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this code, I was able to adapt it to a AreaChart. Hope it helps others..

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6gz2Q/

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>

<div id="creativeCommons" style="text-align: center; width: 400px;">
    <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/deed.en_US"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="http://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-sa/3.0/88x31.png" /></a><br /><span xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" href="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/InteractiveResource" property="dct:title" rel="dct:type">Code to turn on or off data series by clicking on legend entries</span> by <span xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" property="cc:attributionName">Andrew Gallant</span> is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/deed.en_US">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License</a>.
</div>

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y 1');
    data.addColumn({type: 'boolean', role: 'certainty'});
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y 2');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'boolean', role: 'certainty'});
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y 3');
    data.addColumn({type: 'boolean', role: 'certainty'});

    // add random data
    var y1 = 50, y2 = 50, y3 = 50;
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        y1 += ~~(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, ~~(Math.random() * 2));
        y2 += ~~(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, ~~(Math.random() * 2));
        y3 += ~~(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, ~~(Math.random() * 2));
        data.addRow([i, y1, (~~(Math.random() * 2) == 1), y2, y2.toString(), (~~(Math.random() * 2) == 1), y3, (~~(Math.random() * 2) == 1)]);
    }

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
        width: 600,
        height: 400
    }
});

// create columns array
var columns = [0];
/* the series map is an array of data series
 * "column" is the index of the data column to use for the series
 * "roleColumns" is an array of column indices corresponding to columns with roles that are associated with this data series
 * "display" is a boolean, set to true to make the series visible on the initial draw
 */
var seriesMap = [{
    column: 1,
    roleColumns: [2],
    display: true
}, {
    column: 3,
    roleColumns: [4, 5],
    display: true
}, {
    column: 6,
    roleColumns: [7],
    display: false
}];
var columnsMap = {};
var series = [];
for (var i = 0; i < seriesMap.length; i++) {
    var col = seriesMap[i].column;
    columnsMap[col] = i;
    // set the default series option
    series[i] = {};
    if (seriesMap[i].display) {
        // if the column is the domain column or in the default list, display the series
        columns.push(col);
    }
    else {
        // otherwise, hide it
        columns.push({
            label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
            type: data.getColumnType(col),
            sourceColumn: col,
            calc: function () {
                return null;
            }
        });
        // backup the default color (if set)
        if (typeof(series[i].color) !== 'undefined') {
            series[i].backupColor = series[i].color;
        }
        series[i].color = '#CCCCCC';
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < seriesMap[i].roleColumns.length; j++) {
        columns.push(seriesMap[i].roleColumns[j]);
    }
}

chart.setOption('series', series);

function showHideSeries () {
    var sel = chart.getChart().getSelection();
    // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
    if (sel.length > 0) {
        // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
        if (sel[0].row == null) {
            var col = sel[0].column;
            if (typeof(columns[col]) == 'number') {
                var src = columns[col];

                // hide the data series
                columns[col] = {
                    label: data.getColumnLabel(src),
                    type: data.getColumnType(src),
                    sourceColumn: src,
                    calc: function () {
                        return null;
                    }
                };

                // grey out the legend entry
                series[columnsMap[src]].color = '#CCCCCC';
            }
            else {
                var src = columns[col].sourceColumn;

                // show the data series
                columns[col] = src;
                series[columnsMap[src]].color = null;
            }
            var view = chart.getView() || {};
            view.columns = columns;
            chart.setView(view);
            chart.draw();
        }
    }
}

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries);

// create a view with the default columns
var view = {
    columns: columns
};
chart.draw();
}

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```